# Does Fluid not support web fonts?

Tags: macos, font, fluid.app

I am right in saying that [Fluid.app](http://fluidapp.com) does not support Web Fonts?

The fonts on this page looks nothing like in Safari or Chrome:
http://www.typography.com/cloud/welcome/

And I have tried whitelisting the following domains in the Preference, but without luck.

```
*cloud.typography.com*
*typography.com*
*cloudfront.net*
```

Comment: I can confirm that the fonts aren't displaying on fluid for me either. I also have some weird issues with gmail, so I think the version of webkit it is based on is a bit behind.

Comment: oh, I forgot to mention: I thought that it might be because I have glimmer blocker installed (a proxy that removes ads), but it was not active when I tested to see if the webfonts were working.